# How to read everything inside a double quoted string?

Tags: c++, extract, iostream

I'm quite new to C++. I'm writing a program that reads data from a file and puts it into an object. I'm doing this to try to understand the iostream better.

Each line of the file contains an alphanumeric ID in the format nxn, where n is some integer, and x is some character, a color, another integer, and then a location. Here's an example

```
17832X9647 "blue" 100 "New York City"
```

Unfortunately, the code that I've written doesn't get all of the final string, since it has spaces in it. So, I tried writing a function that would return all of the text inside double quotes (not including the double quotes) and putting it inside the input stream, while still preserving the whitespaces and discarding the double quotes. Unfortunately, that also did not work, so now I'm sitting here scratching my head, not knowing what to do, and it's because I fundamentally don't understand how the iostream works. What can I do to fix this? I would really, really not like to restructure my whole program, because I want to learn exactly how I'm treating the iostream wrong. Getting this thing to work in the most efficient way isn't important to me, just that I understand more about the iostream.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

string ReadDoubleString(istream & in)
{
    string output_string;

    char ch = '\"';

    in.ignore(ch); //i'm thinking that this will make the extraction skip any double quotes
    in >> output_string;

    return output_string;
}


//begin class declaration and implementation for Widget
class Widget
{
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Widget&);
    
    public:
        string ID;
        string color;
        int Age;
        string location;

        void setAttributes(string, string, int, string);
};

void Widget::setAttributes(string ID, string color, int Age, string location)
{
    this->ID = ID;
    this->color = color;
    this->Age = Age;
    this->location = location;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Widget& output_widget)
{
    int input_ID_pt1;
    char input_ID_pt2;
    int input_ID_pt3;
    string full_ID;

    string input_color;

    int input_Age;

    string input_location;


    in >> input_ID_pt1 >> input_ID_pt2 >> input_ID_pt3;
    input_color = ReadDoubleString(in);
    in >> input_Age;
    input_location = ReadDoubleString(in);  

    full_ID = to_string(input_ID_pt1) + input_ID_pt2 + to_string(input_ID_pt3);

    output_widget.setAttributes(full_ID, input_color, input_Age, input_location);

    return in;
}
//end class declaration and implementation for Widget


int main()
{
    string file_name;

    cout << "enter file name" << endl;
    cin >> file_name;

    ifstream newFile(file_name);
    
    if (newFile.is_open())
    {
        Widget w1;

        newFile >> w1; 

        cout << w1.ID << endl;
        cout << w1.color << endl;
        cout << w1.Age << endl;
        cout << w1.location << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "could not open file!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My program ends up returning this when I use the data from earlier.

```
17832X9647
//empty line
0
//empty line
//empty line
```

Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: This looks like CSV (comma seperated values) using spaces as separators. With other programming languages I'd recommend to use CSV library but in C++ linking external libraries is an advanced topic. On the other side you'd learn something important and a library is usually a very stable solution. One possible library is https://github.com/d99kris/rapidcsv/

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thank you for responding so quickly. I'll try to look into that library, but surely there's a way to do this with just the standard C++ library, right?

Comment: Yes, of course, but C++ is the only programming language I know where the developers keep reinventing the wheel. With all other programming languages even beginners would immediately install an external library for the problem. Reading good external libraries will also teach you best practices.

Comment: @ThomasSablik The reason I don't really want to install an external library is that getting this program to work is really secondary. What I'm really wanting out of this question is to understand why the iostream doesn't work in the way that I think it does. But, again, thank you for showing me that library. It seems really useful.

Comment: `in >> output_string;` is a [formatted read](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt). It reads until the first whitespace. You should read the whole line with `std::getline` and parse it yourself.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ok. Thank you. That explains a lot, but how come my output looks the way it does?

Comment: The best tool to find this out is your debugger. You can step line by line through your code and see which line produces which output while you're able to see the values of your variables.

Comment: The problem is `in.ignore(ch);`. The first parameter is the count: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore That means that you're skipping up to `'"'` (34 in ASCII) characters until you find a white space character. It's probably helpful to know that `char` is a simple number type with range -128 - 127 or 0 - 255. You can use characters everywhere numbers are expected in C++.